# facebook api get feed with pictures

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Java to get user's feed from Facebook graph API.
/me/feed works fine but I want to get the pictures of posts if available.
On the Graph api explorer , The following URL works to retrieve pictures:

/me/feed?fields=picture,message,story

But when I change my code from:

```
 final GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/feed", null, HttpMethod.GET, gCallback);
```

to

```
final GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/feed?fields=message,story", null, HttpMethod.GET, gCallback);
```

it starts crashing with RuntimeException:

```
02-26 16:30:34.751: D/AndroidRuntime(28980): Shutting down VM
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): Process: com.aktuna.gear.facebook, PID: 28980
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.aktuna.gear.facebook/com.aktuna.gear.facebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4925)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4968)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1849)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.aktuna.gear.facebook.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:71)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.aktuna.gear.facebook.MainActivity$1.onSuccess(MainActivity.java:1)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.finishLogin(LoginManager.java:508)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:192)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.facebook.login.LoginManager$1.onActivityResult(LoginManager.java:140)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl.onActivityResult(CallbackManagerImpl.java:82)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at com.aktuna.gear.facebook.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:107)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7137)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-26 16:30:34.751: E/AndroidRuntime(28980):    ... 9 more
```

what is wrong ?
why the graph request returns null if I add the fields to my request ?

thanks

Comment: Likely your SDK needs the fields specified in a different way. Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: the documentation does not give any clue about getting pictures from /me/feed  . or I don't understand ? there's nothing more than a few words here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed

Comment: You are confusing API and SDK.

Comment: ok I got the sdk reference here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current  but I still could not find the relevant information. how can I get the picture field in /me/feed output ?

Comment: Go check the basic examples in the Calling the Graph API section, it shows how to ask for fields.

Comment: thank you. examples worked for me. I would expect to find out in the reference. anyway, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @CBroe I was able to find the answer in the examples of SDK reference.

here it is for future occasions:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```